# How do I implement gradual load in App Inventor?

Tags: app-inventor

I am workimg om a cookBook app usimg App Inventor. When the app loads it is extremely slow. The main reason I found is that this is due to multi image loading on the initial load.

For example if the app decides to display 100 recipies to the user then it loads all 100 of them including images at once. This is taking the vast amount of time.

I want to implement gradual load but not sure how this can be done in App Inventor. 
How can this be done?

Comment: I'd advise looking in the AppInventor support area and forums if there are any.

Comment: you might want to use an extension... see the extensions directory here https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php